# $f$ is continuous at $x=c$ if and only if $lim_{h\rightarrow0} f(c+h) = f(c)$

Tags: calculus

I thought about it quite a long time. And came up with $x = c+h, x\rightarrow c \Rightarrow h\rightarrow0$

But I am not sure if the process is right.

I want to figure this out on my own as much as possible. So it would be grateful if you give me just a little hint.

Thank you

Comment: More generally in a metric space it is true that function $f$ is
continuous at $c$ iff $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f\left(x\right)=f\left(c\right)$.
In $\mathbb{R}$ $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f\left(x\right)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}f\left(c+h\right)$.

Comment: What definition of continuity are you using?

Comment: @dani_s lim_x->c f(x) = f(c) and limit and value at c exist. Is there other definition of continuity? I don't know but this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to be more rigorous than that if you want to prove your statement. I suggest you prove the statement in the traditional way of proving if and only if statements:

- Prove that if $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(c+h) = f(c)$, then the function $f$ is continous at $c$.
- Prove that if $f$ is continous at $c$, the limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(c+h)$ exists and equals $f(c)$

Comment: I've gone for that, too. But then I don't know how to start with limh→0f(c+h)=f(c)

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with what you will do. First, write down the definition of continuity of $f$ in $c$. Then, write the definition of what it means that $L$ is a limit of $f(c+h)$ as $h$ approaches $0$.

Comment: I think i figure it out. so the precise definition of ' lim_h->0 f(c+h) = f(c) ' is

Comment: The definition is available here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_the_real_line

Comment: My try went like this. 0<abs(x-c)<d => abs{f(x)-f(c)}<e. Let's Say x is substituted by c+h. Then, 0<abs(h-0)<d => abs{f(c+h)-f(c)}<e. So lim_h->0 f(c+h) = f(c). but I doubt the last part is right. Because I think I haven't seen that kind of definition in the chapter about precise definition of limit. And sorry for my typing.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks for your reply!